saved_changes is empty after persisting changes on a Rails model
We have a Rails 6.1 application running an after_commit callback to look into saved_changes value to run some background workers. But the issue is saved_changes returns empty if a model has accepts_nested_attributes_for. It is not only after_commit other callbacks like before_save, and around_save also return empty saved_changes value.
For example.
on models/profile.rb
after_commit :run_worker, on: :update

belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

In this case saved_changes is {} but if I remove the accepts_nested_attributes_for it works fine and gives me the changed value.
It is a known issue caused by double saves as mentioned on this GH issue. The workaround for 7.1 is adding config on the application.rb
config.active_record.run_commit_callbacks_on_first_saved_instances_in_transaction = true

This default is for Rails 7.1 and does not work for 6.1. Has someone else run through this issue and has a workaround?


It is not only after_commit other callbacks like before_save, and around_save also return empty saved_changes value.

saved_change is only present after a record is saved, so it is expected that it's empty in before_save callback, and it should be empty in around_save callback as well until the record is saved there.
Before a record is saved the dirty state is stored in changes object (not saved_changes).

To address your problem I would suggest to save changes in a custom attribute to use later in after_save/after_commit callbacks. Something like this:
attr_accessor :my_saved_changes

before_save :save_dirty_state

def save_dirty_state
  self.my_saved_changes = changes
end


UPDATED SUGGESTION GIVEN THE COMMENT BELOW:
If I understand correctly those 2 saves happen inside 1 transaction, so after_commit callback will be called just once. You can probably rely on that and only set my_saved_changes attribute from my proposal only if it's not set yet (and then reset it in after_commit callback):
attr_accessor :my_saved_changes

before_save :save_dirty_state
# Have this callback to execute the last:
after_commit :reset_dirty_state

def save_dirty_state
  # Note the change of assignment here ('||=' operator instead of '=')
  self.my_saved_changes ||= changes
end

def reset_dirty_state
  self.my_saved_changes = nil
end


Thank you for the answer @GProst, but this solution does not work. Rails call before_save twice. The first call assigned the dirty changes but the second call reset all those previously assigned dirty changes. Looking further, it found similar issues happening with other people too and it seems like a Rails bug.

I see, I updated my suggestion

Thank you GProst, the answer works like a charm.

In relying heavily on @GProst's Answer while addressing your comment, it appears you could hack this together as:
after_commit :preserve_changes

attr_writer :my_saved_changes

# just so #my_saved_changes always returns a Hash
def my_saved_changes
  @my_saved_changes ||= {} 
end 

def preserve_changes
  self.my_saved_changes = saved_changes if saved_changes?
end

This should avoid the overwrite on the secondary save since there are no changes to save and thus saved_changes? would be false.
If you wanted to use a before_save as suggested in the referenced post you could use has_changes_to_save? as a guard instead.
